# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale when generating plot with huge data, using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a ggplot with one geom_line and two rectangle functions. Lets just take a small example:

```
annots = c(1,2,5,9,14,17,19,4,22,34)
x=1:10
bits = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
inside = ifelse(bits==1, x, NA)

fstData <- data.frame(x, annots, inside)

start = c(1,7)
end = c(4,10)

sndData <- data.frame(start, end)
```

Now when I want to generate the plot, I want the first rectangles to be drawn depending on the information "inside", and the second based on the sndData data frame. So as far as I understood I have to define the aesthetics, right??

```
plot = ggplot(fstData) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=annots)) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = inside - 0.5, xmax = inside + 0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.3, fill = "blue") + geom_rect(data = sndData, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = 2, ymax = 5))
```

However, when I do it with the upper example, the plot is created. But in my real data (which I import from other source files, the x axis has x=1:5528383 entries), I get the upper error message.

I tried to find the solution in the internet, however I cannot find the real solution to my problem - as it is working for the small dataset which is confusing.

UPDATE:

So the second rectangle is the one making the problems. Here is how I set the values:

```
sndData = read.table("/table.txt", header=FALSE)
names(sndData) = c("start", "end")
```

The command dput(head(sndData)) gives me: (and this is just a part of it)

```
structure(list(start = structure(c(1051L, 2838L, 2094L, 3084L, 
4639L, 4931L), .Label = c("1001326", "1002724", "1003043", "1003655", 
"1005193", "1005687", "100607", "1006799", "1007671", "1008920", 
"1009736", "1010617", "1011890", "1012260", "1013075", "1014367", 
"1015078", "101692", "1017034", "1017441", "1017858", "1018129", 
"1018912", "1019902", "1020729", "1021936", "1023079", "1024029", 
"1024934", "1025463", "1026870", "1028235", "1028567", "103008", 
"1030099", "1031121", "1031789", "1032512", "1033261", "1034207", 
"1034736", "1035347", "1036698", "1037364", "1037684", "1038511", 
"1039623", "1041064", "1042102", "104249", "1043953", "1044933", 
"1046729", "1048086", "1049207", "1050862", "1051942", "1053081", 
"105370", "1055100", "1055647", "1055998", "1058794", "1060183", 
"1062368", "1062496", "1063112", "1063635", "1064033", "1065759", 
"10659", "1066257", "1066951", "106838", "1069497", "1070092", 
"1071680", "1072480", "1072931", "1073862", "10741", "1074449", 
"1074724", "1075147", "1075700", "1076152", "107760", "1077996", 
"1078652", "1079441", "1079752", "1080062", "1081778", "1082243", 
"1082929", "1083594", "1083802", "1084205", "1084758", "1085323", 
"108587", "1085878", "1086336", "1087456", "1088027", "1088540",
```

Comment: Usually you'll get that error message if one of your variables is not of an expected type (e.g. you are trying to plot a continuous variable and character variable on the same scale). I can replicate your error by changing `sndData` to be `sndData <- data.frame(start=as.character(start), end=as.character(end), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, however I don't know exactly what is going on without sample data that reflects your actual data. It might be useful to post a `dput(head())` of your actual data.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, however the data is very big so I just tried to add a cut -off of the second data, which is the one making problems. 
it is basically a file with two columns, a start and end position.